# Linkedin REST API retrieve status updates of a user

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve the status updates of the authenticated user with the REST API. Is there a way to do that? I only can find a way to retrieve the status updates of the companies the user has admin rights of.

Comment: do you found any solution??.. Please Share/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer possible with the standard LinkedIn API (If you look at their REST console, you can see all the public methods: https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?apig_cc=1).

You now need to join their partner program in order to access additional API methods now: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs